# Visual Studio 2017 RC installation

Tags: visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2015 installed with a lot of features like Xamarin etc, VS 2015 is 20 Gb large in my pc. My question is, can I install VS 2017 RC and use all adds I added for VS2015? So I don't have to uninstall VS 2015 and all it features and then install all that for VS2017, as I have space issues?

Comment: Often plugins are versioned. So a plugin that works in VS 2015 may or may not work in 2017. Also, there may be differences between the plugin between 2015 and 2017. Also... I would recommend against using an RC as your primary or only IDE. RCs are, by definition, unstable. Fun to play with, but not a good choice if you are working on professional projects with deadlines and customers.

Comment: @JDB thanks for the info. How long they would need to make final release? Is release date known?

Comment: I don't know the GA release date, and I imagine that if it's reported somewhere, then it's an estimate subject to change. Of interest: VS 2017 RC known issues: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#knownissues

Comment: You should stick to VS2015 at this moment. VS2017 might be installed side by side, but many extensions might cause issues. For instance, Xamarin will be upgraded to a test version, and your stable version with VS2015 will be uninstalled, which can be a serious problem if you do ship mobile apps. As Build 2017 is in May, we can roughly estimate the release day of VS2017 to be around that period (or before that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to re-install Xamarin as a workflow in VS2017 RC. I assume it's the same for other workloads.

VS2017 allows for more modular installation, though, so you may be able to try one workload at a time.